# What should I change or delete in order to fix this code so the rest may work fine?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <h1>iostream <h2> 
#include <h1>cmath<h2>// for + of months, days, and years
#include <h1>fstream<h2> //for in and output
#include <h1>cstdlib<h2>
#include <h1>string<h2>//for string type

using namespace std;
class Device {//Input and store Device Description and Serial Numbers
protected:
    string  serial_number;
    string device_description;
public:
    Device() {
        serial_number = ("6DCMQ32");
        device_description = ("TheDell");
    }
    Device(string s, string d) {
        serial_number = s;
        device_description = d;
    }
};
class Test {
protected:
    string Test_Description;
    static int recent_month, recent_day, recent_year, new_month;
    static int nmonth, next_month, next_day, next_year, max_day;
public:
    static void getMonth() {//Calculates the next/new month
        next_month = recent_month + nmonth;
        new_month = next_month % 12;
        if (next_month >= 12) {
            cout << "The next Date: " << new_month << " / ";
        }
        else {
            cout << "The next Date: " << next_month << " / ";
        }
    }
    static void getDay() {  //Calculates day of next month
        if (new_month == 4 || new_month == 6 || new_month == 9 || new_month == 11) {
            max_day = 30;
        }
        else if (new_month == 2) {
            max_day = 29;
        }
        else {
            max_day = 31;
        }
        if (recent_day > max_day) {
            cout << max_day << " / ";
        }
        else {
            cout << recent_day << " / ";
        }
    }
    static void getYear() {//Calculates the year of the next number of months
        next_year = recent_year + next_month;
        if (next_year >= 12) {
            cout << recent_year + (next_month / 12) << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << next_year << endl;
        }
    }
    static void getDate() {
        Test::getMonth(), Test::getDay(), Test::getYear();
    }
};
int Test::recent_month, Test::recent_day, Test::recent_year, 
Test::new_month;
int Test::nmonth, Test::next_month, Test::next_day, Test::next_year, 
Test::max_day;
class Lab : public Device, public Test {//Class Lab is a Child of Class Test and Class Device
protected:
    static int n;
public:
    friend istream & operator>>(istream & cin, const Lab & lab) {
        cout << "Enter Device Description and serial number: ";
        getline(cin, lab.device_description);//This is where the error is
        getline(cin, lab.serial_number);//This is where the error is
        cout << "Enter Test Description: ";
        getline(cin, lab.Test_Description);//This is where the error is
        cout << "Enter number of months: ";
        cin >> lab.nmonth;
        cout << "Enter the most recent date(mm/dd/yyyy): ";
        cin >> lab.recent_month >> lab.recent_day >> lab.recent_year;
        return cin;
    }
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & cout, const Lab & lab) {
        cout << lab.device_description << " ";
        cout << lab.serial_number << endl;
        cout << lab.Test_Description << endl;
        getDate();
        return cout;
   }
   static void getFile() {
       cout << "Enter the number of devices: ";
       cin >> n;
       Lab *obj = new Lab[n];
       if (obj == 0) {
           cout << "Memory Error";
           exit(1);
       }
       for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
           cin >> obj[i];
       }
       ofstream myfile("Device.dat", ios::binary);
       myfile.write((char *)obj, n * sizeof(Lab));
       Lab *obj2 = new Lab[n];
       ifstream file2("Device.dat", ios::binary);
       if (obj2 == 0) {
           cout << "Memory Error";
           exit(1);
       }
       file2.read((char *)obj2, n * sizeof(Lab));
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           cout << obj2[i];
           cout << endl;
       }
       delete[] obj2;
    }
    void getSearch(){

    }
 };
 void main() {
     Lab L;
     L.getFile();
     system("pause");
 }
```

> //Error  C2665   'std::getline': none of the 2 overloads could convert all 
>       the argument types

/*
      Purpose: is to enter the number of months for the next test date of device with input of serial number, Device Description, Test Description, recent date, and the number of months of two tests. At the end the program must be searched by having the user to input the serial number and the next date, if these two are valid everything in the device is listed out.
    */<

Comment: _"I Keep on getting this error."_ Which error specifically?

Comment: Show a complete program, including the headers, that duplicate your error.  If I took the code you posted and attempted to compile, I would get errors also.

Comment: It seems that std::getline function receive arguments with a wrong type

Comment: `const Lab &` lab should be just `Lab &`. You cannot write to const reference parameters.

Comment: . o O ( i am getting so tired of people unable to indent their code )

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why don't write that as an answer, bro?

Comment: @Swordfish I don't write answers for _off-topic_ questions. I consider that as a typo, and voted to close so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That q shows much more bs than just a misplaced `const` to target an answer at.

Comment: @Swordfish Well, feel free to write an answer and use what I've commented.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I love 2nd hand stuff *cough*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't name your parameters like objects of the standard library (`cin`).

For an argument to be modifiable it must not be a reference to a constant entity.

Also, a `std::istream` bound `operator<<()` overload should not do output, but only extract the object required from the stream.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am just a beginner still learner. Thanks for you help